# Flutter set notification icon like big app icon

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter2.0

Hello I want my firsbase push notification’s app icon should look like big icon at left and title at right side.
Here I am attaching an example.
I am able to set the icon but its coming as very small and totally at the top.
Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: basically you need to create custom layout for notification. All big apps that you are talking about does that.

Comment: Is it possible to create custom layout in flutter as I know I have to create in XML and link it to my flutter app but do you have any example ?

Comment: how can we create custom layout for notification can you please tell me @AnkitMishra

Comment: @RaviSoni need to design layout file and use it. Try searching some good blogs on search engine about the same.

Comment: @AnkitMishra I know how to create a custom XML layout I'll do it but how to use it in flutter for notification I tried searching but didn't find something relevant to this if you have done such a task can you share some references?